# Wordpress Javascript not working on Edge browser

Tags: wordpress

I have this site 
https://www.lifft.ca/listing-report/Vancouver/1055579/

It loads the listing and then uses javascript to change some classes so it's styled better. if opened on chrome, it works fine but javascript doesn't take effect on Edge browser. Not sure why it's happening. It opens unstyled on Edge.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to change these CSS classes and we might be able to help out.

Comment: That's the JS fiel that does it. https://www.lifft.ca/wp-content/plugins/wealty/public/scripts/ihomefinder-@849f3b09@.js?ver=5.2.4